# My daemon process in Linux getting stuck randomly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon

I have a daemon process, which stuck randomly. The /proc/pid/stack shows this:

```
[<0>] do_sys_poll+0x486/0x610
[<0>] __x64_sys_poll+0xa9/0x140
[<0>] do_syscall_64+0x59/0xc0
[<0>] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
```

strace -cp pid, outputs this:

[image]

Does it mean its stuck on do_sys_poll? What do_sys_poll does and how to find why its stuck here?

Comment: It waits for data to arrive to a socket (see `man poll`).

Comment: My script add log into a log file when it start, then calls AWS SQS to poll message. Can I know, if there is some issue in my script which is causing it to hang or there is some system setting?

Comment: You probably can know if you debug your program.

Comment: The program works fine, but I have put it in daemon to run continuously in few seconds. It would work most of the times, but like after few days it will stuck somewhere, which I dont know why. The process is in S mode and the stack trace of that process is showing as in question.

Comment: I have added strace output as well in question.